# How to post a server call through http from ip address in angular 2

Tags: angular, server, ip

When i tried connecting to my serve rthrough ip its shown an error in my console but when i tried through postman  it worked.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

My error,

```
 core.umd.js:3066 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

My code,

```
onSubmit(form:any){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('193.568.0.14:5000/api/signup', form.value, { headers: headers}).subscribe(
        response => {
            if(response.json().error_code == 0){
            }

        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add - http://

```
onSubmit(form:any){
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   this.http.post('http://193.568.0.14:5000/api/signup', form.value, { headers: headers}).subscribe(
    response => {
        if(response.json().error_code == 0){
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: HI Igor,thats almost worked but i got this error now

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You have to allow origin on server side becase your angular 2 app is not on the same domain like your server, or you can install this chrome plugin in development purposes  in case if app in production will be on the same server. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Hey Igor,i am able to insert new record but i am not getting any values from client side i.e inserting empty record.

Comment: Can you please post the code where are you getting the results from server?

Comment: Hi Igor,sorry for the late reply...I am using the same code which i posted.

Comment: I been searching for this answer everywhere! Thank you for this!